# How to properly configure MSVC's compiler options with QtCreator?

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli, clr, qt-creator, qmake

I'm trying to migrate from Visual Studio 2008 to QtCreator in a project that uses C++/CLI extensions. This just means that I need to use the **-clr** compiler option when compiling my files.

I've managed to add it by adding the following line to my project.pro file:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -clr
```

However, there is a conflicting option in my compiler's call that is conflicting with this one. It is the **-EHsc** option. But I can't find where these options get included and how to disable it. My default call to the compiler is looking like this:

```
cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t- -clr -Zi -MDd -GR -EHsc -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -I"<PATH_TO_QT>\4.8.0\msvc2010\include\QtCore" -I"<PATH_TO_QT>\4.8.0\msvc2010\include\QtGui" -I"<PATH_TO_QT>\4.8.0\msvc2010\include" -I"<PATH_TO_QT>\4.8.0\msvc2010\include\ActiveQt" -I"debug" -I"." -I"..\MyProject" -I"." -I"<PATH_TO_QT>\4.8.0\msvc2010\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010" -Fodebug\ @<SOME_TEMP_FILE>.jom
```

Any ideas on how to achieve what I want here?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. It was in another qmake's environment variable. The solution was this:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -clr
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_STL_ON -= -EHsc
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_EXCEPTIONS_ON -= -EHsc
```

I've got a lot of warnings in the Qt library but I will get into those later.

Comment: Hey, could you tell me how did get rid of the warnings?

Comment: Sorry, don't remember