# Is the abort/retry/ignore on assert Windows only? Can it be activated on Linux somehow?

Tags: c++, c, linux, assert

I'm playing around with `assert` and am surprised to find the Windows dialogue of what to do at assertion actually quite useful in certain conditions, e.g. letting user decide whether to carry on at their own risk despite the application being in an undocumented state because of detecting a formally unsupported platform configuration (which will probably work anyway, just need to test it and update the white-list).

[image]

But for what I know the dialogue is Windows only. Linux terminates the application. Any way to get it working on Linux?

Comment: I tried `assert` on Windows and got "*This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.*". No abort/retry/ignore.

Comment: @melpomene Added picture of what I get on assert.

Comment: This assertion dialog pops up only under debugger and is not intended to be used by end users. On Linux assertion failure will typically trigger `SIGABRT` that can be potentially handled by the attached debugger.

Comment: built using release configuration. I have to `#undef NDEBUG` to keep `assert` from disappearing.

Comment: Well, yes. `#define NDEBUG 1` disables `assert`. That's what it's there for.

Comment: You confuse compilers, operating systems and runtime libraries here. The dialogue you see here is the result of the Visual C++ compiler having been invoked with the `/MTd` or `/MDd` flag in order to have the resulting executable binary use a special debug runtime library. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/debug-routines. The dialog box in your question is one of the features offered by that special runtime.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Good stuff, that explains alot! I use the Qt Creator and told it to do a release build. Got no idea what flags are used and libraries linked. In any case, I have no issues with shipping debug builds to users.

Comment: @Andreas: I don't know Qt Creator, but it surely has some way of telling you with which flags the compiler should be invoked? I've searched for "qt creator set msvc compiler flags" on Google, and the first result was this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772651/how-to-properly-configure-msvcs-compiler-options-with-qtcreator

Comment: on Linux crash log is generated and stored in `/var/log/crashes/` directory. Crash report should contain needed information and call stack of all threads.